R function to extract two word phrases in a list which also contains the first word as a separate string
I have a data frame with a string column, and a list of words/phrases which I would like to extract from the column. I have used the following code.
df <- data.frame(string = c("A rose is a woody perennial flower of the genus Rosa","A rose is a flower and a red rose is a symbol of love"))

rx <- rebus::or("red", "rose", "red rose", "flower")

extracts <- sapply(df$string, function(x) stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(x, rx, simplify = F))


this is what I get...
$A rose is a woody perennial flower of the genus Rosa
[1] "rose"   "flower"
$A rose is a flower and a red rose is a symbol of love
[1] "rose"   "flower" "red"  "rose"
what I need is to :
1- also get "red rose" extracted
2- for expressions with a common first word I want to keep only the one that is longer i.e. the one with more number of words (e.g. if I have both red and red rose in the 'rx', I want to keep red rose only.
$A rose is a woody perennial flower of the genus Rosa
[1] "rose"   "flower"
$A rose is a flower and a red rose is a symbol of love
[1] "red rose"   "flower"

You say "for expressions with a common first word I want to keep only the one that is longer i.e. the one with more number of words (e.g. if I have both red and red rose in the 'rx', I want to keep red rose only." but then that would give "rose", "red rose" and "flower" for the second string. Do you mean ANY word that's already in a two word extract?

Here's a function that should do the trick:
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

strings <- c("A rose is a woody perennial flower of the genus Rosa",
             "A rose is a flower and a red rose is a symbol of love")

rx <- c("red", "rose", "red rose", "flower")

custom_str_extract <- function(strings, rx){

  # vector of matching elements in rx for each string
  matches <-
    map(rx,
        \(x){
          str_extract_all(strings, x) |>
            map(unique)
          }) |>
    pmap(c)
  
  # list of vectors: elements of rx contained in each element of rx
  rx_contained <-
    map(rx, \(x) str_detect(x, rx) & !x == rx) |>
    map(\(x) rx[x]) |> 
    set_names(rx)
  
  # For each vector of matches, remove contained rx elements
  map(matches,
      \(x){
        contained <- list_c(rx_contained[x])
        x[!x %in% contained]
      })
  }

custom_str_extract(strings, rx)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "rose"   "flower"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "red rose" "flower"

Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for the suggestion. The code ran very slowly although I just performed it on one row (my rx list is more than 5000). so I don't think it would be practical on a df with 8000 rows. and when it finished it didn't give me the desired extracts....  your code is complex for me (I'm not advanced in R) so I don't know why. thanks anyway.

Hi @ayeh. Am I right in understanding that you have two vectors of equal length, rx and string, both contained within the same dataframe?

A minimal example of your actual data would be helpful

Hi & TNX.. Providing the data is not  possible as it's in Persian. but to clarify, I have a data frame of herbal formulations (about 8000 rows). The string is a long string describing the formulations. The rx is a list of herbs I want to extract from the text (as components of formulations). some herbs are single words others are two or three words. e.g. I have both "enab" (meaning grape) and "enab salab"  (black nightshade). so I would not want "enab" to be extract in a text that mentions "enab salab" ... EXCEPT of course when they appear in different locations of the same text

@ayeh It being in Persian wouldn't be an issue.

With {stringi}, the functions are already vectorized, so there's no need to use sapply. You can add the names after if necessary.
To get only 'red rose' instead of 'red' and 'red rose', it's a matter of priority in your regex. Try rebus::or("red rose", "red", "rose", "flower") instead.
df <- data.frame(string = c("A rose is a woody perennial flower of the genus Rosa","A rose is a flower and a red rose is a symbol of love"))
extracts <- stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(df$string, rebus::or("red rose", "red", "rose", "flower"))
names(extracts) <- df$string

will give
> extracts
$`A rose is a woody perennial flower of the genus Rosa`
[1] "rose"   "flower"
$`A rose is a flower and a red rose is a symbol of love`
[1] "rose"     "flower"   "red rose"


In case you meant not repeating word and not just the expressions with a common first word. You can add a subsequent check like:
extracts <- lapply(extracts, function(x){
  toRemove <- c()
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      isOneWord <- stringi::stri_count_words(x[i]) == 1
      isAlreadyFound <- any(stringi::stri_detect_fixed(x[-i], x[i]))
      if (isOneWord && isAlreadyFound) {
          toRemove <- c(toRemove, i)
      }
  }
  if (length(toRemove)) {
      x[-toRemove]
  } else {
      x
  }
})

Which checks if any one word expression is already in a another one and removes it if so.

thankyou for the help. I arranged my rx list based on word count and checked it on one row and think it worked. This way the output was just the two word phrases ...

I checked the solution more thoroughly.  In some instances I have like 'red rose" and 'yellow rose" both. so they are arranged by word count and they both have two words so I get one only (red rose but not yellow rose).

Is 'yellow rose' in the pattern?

yes. there when there are both red rose and yellow rose, only red rose (the one that comes first in alphabetical order) is extracted.

Can you update your example? When running my code with an added sentence containing both 'yellow rose' and 'red rose' and with 'yellow rose' added to the rebus::or, I get both. Can't tell what you're doing differently if you aren't showing me.
